# Order by Date then String MVC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, record

If multiple challenges share the same `date` how can we make it that `goal` challenges always appear before `habit` challenges?

**challenges_controller**

```
def index
  @challenges = current_user.challenges.order("date ASC")
  @challenges_by_years = (@challenges).group_by { |t| [t.date.year, t.date.month] }
end
```

**challenge.rb**

```
CATEGORY = ['goal', 'habit']
scope :goal,  -> { where(category: 'goal') }
scope :habit,  -> { where(category: 'habit') }
```

**challenge record**

```
#<Challenge:0x007fd464c67b90
 id: 5,
 name: "Write 3 Gratitudes",
 date: Mon, 06 Mar 2017,
 category: "habit",  # The string is always either "goal" or "habit".
 user_id: 1,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order by `date` first and then order by `category`

```
@challenges = current_user.challenges.order("date, category")
```

The above query will order the records by date and the records with same date will again reordered by category i.e `'goal'` and `'habit'`

Comment: Our of curiosity how does ordering by `category` alone default to `goal` before `habit`. Is it bc of less letters or the order of scope lines?

Comment: It's string ordering `alphabetical order` so `g` comes before `h`

Answer (score 1):

```
current_user.challenges.order("date ASC, category: ASC")
```

because `goal` is less than `habit`.

```
current_user.challenges.order(:date, :category) # a bit shorter notation, does the same thing
```